# How to remove unwanted text which is appearing above keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield, stripe-payments

I am using `STPPaymentCardTextField` which accepts card number and other details. When I click on the `textField`, the keyboard appears as showed in image.

[image]

What is that **SIM_LABEL SIM_VALUE** text? How to remove it?

Comment: please share your code .

Comment: I have just taken a view and assigned it's class as STPPaymentCardTextField and an outlet.

Comment: Try the_textfield.inputAccessoryView = nil

Comment: @SeanLintern88 tried your code...not working